# How to Store temporal data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, arduino, firebase-realtime-database, esp8266

I make measures every minutes and I'm searching for a good way to store these measures in Firebase.

I was first thinking to store every value In a different autogenerated Key

```
measures : {
    KEY1 : {
        measure : 456 ,
        timestamp : 2016-11-08T08:54:12
    },
    KEY2 : {
        measure : ... ,
        timestamp : ...
    },
    KEY3 : {...}
    ...
}
```

But this is not sustainable, it cannot run forever.

---

My second thought would be decide that I need only the last 10 values and then

- read the 9th last recorded measure --> store it in the 10th place
- read the 8th --> store in 9th
- ...
- finaly store my last value in the 1st place

But this might take a lot of reads and writes of I decide to store 100 values or 24 hours every minute = 1440 values.

---

3rd idea : delete old keys

A third idea would be to keep only the 9 last autogenerated keys
and add a new one with the last value. But I don't see how to do that (knowing that I use the arduino-firebase api https://github.com/firebase/firebase-arduino on a esp8266).

---

[EDIT] 4th idea : circular buffer

write values in keys 1 to 60 and then start again from 1

This may be a good solution. The keys might even be coded as hour/minute

---

[EDIT] 5th idea : incremental string

write the values a comma-separated string.
read the current saved string then add the new value ad the beginning and then update the string of values

This has the disadvantage of requiring more and more bandwith

---

Is there a better way?

Comment: why don't you mind to store your data to the cloud systems like [thingspeak](http://thingspeak.com) ?

Comment: I don't know thingspeak, I'm used to firebase. Is it any better?

Comment: I cannot compare them since thingspeak is just a remote storage but Firebase more likely to framework.